# Tensorflow object_detection_tutorial download model error

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I just installed Tensorflow object detection API and try to run [object_detection_tutorial.ipynb](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) to test if it's installed properly.
When I run step of download model:

```
opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
for file in tar_file.getmembers():
 file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
  if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
    tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())
```

Here are the errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-d071c761582d> in <module>()
      1 opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
----> 2 opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
      3 tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
      4 for file in tar_file.getmembers():
      5   file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)

C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in retrieve(self, url, filename, reporthook, data)
   1730             except OSError as msg:
   1731                 pass
-> 1732         fp = self.open(url, data)
   1733         try:
   1734             headers = fp.info()

C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data)
   1696         try:
   1697             if data is None:
-> 1698                 return getattr(self, name)(url)
   1699             else:
   1700                 return getattr(self, name)(url, data)

C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open_http(self, url, data)
   1875     def open_http(self, url, data=None):
   1876         """Use HTTP protocol."""
-> 1877         return self._open_generic_http(http.client.HTTPConnection, url, data)
   1878 
   1879     def http_error(self, url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers, data=None):

C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _open_generic_http(self, connection_factory, url, data)
   1871             return self.http_error(
   1872                 url, response.fp,
-> 1873                 response.status, response.reason, response.msg, data)
   1874 
   1875     def open_http(self, url, data=None):

C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error(self, url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers, data)
   1891                 result = method(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers, data)
   1892             if result: return result
-> 1893         return self.http_error_default(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
   1894 
   1895     def http_error_default(self, url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers):

C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
   1896         """Default error handler: close the connection and raise OSError."""
   1897         fp.close()
-> 1898         raise HTTPError(url, errcode, errmsg, headers, None)
   1899 
   1900     if _have_ssl:

HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: Found
```

My environment: Anaconda3 & win10.
It would be grateful if anyone would help!

Comment: you might need to update DOWNLOAD_BASE for the recent "models/research" refactoring.  That is, all paths: "/models/object_detection/..." are now "/models/research/object_detection/..."

Comment: I will take a try later, but thank you anyway :)@brown.2179